# ASP.NET CORE 5 MVC How Can I Convert Absolut Path To Relative Path?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, path-finding

so in the project a user could upload, download, delete, preview and search for (in real time) a file. The files are stored in a folder called "Uploads" inside of the wwwroot folder. As of now, the code has absolute pathing, but the project will need to be on different computers so I need relative pathing, can anyone help me out with a sample syntax?

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(IFormFile fifile, string category)
        {
            string path = @"C:\Users\panara5\source\repos\Proiect2PracticaClona\Proiect2PracticaClona\wwwroot\Uploads\";
            var fisave = Path.Combine(path, fifile.FileName);
            var stream = new FileStream(fisave, FileMode.Create);
            await fifile.CopyToAsync(stream);

            Files fileModel=new Files()
            {
                info = fifile.FileName,
                category = category
            };

            _fileRepository.AddFile(fileModel);
   
          
            stream.Close();

            files = _fileRepository.GetFileList();

         

            return RedirectToAction("Index",files);
        }
        public IActionResult Index(string id)
        {
            files = _fileRepository.GetFileList();

            if (id == null)
                return View(files);

            List<Files> sortedfiles = new List<Files>();
            foreach (var item in files)
            {
                if (item.category == id)
                {
                    sortedfiles.Add(item);
                }
            }
            
            
            return View(sortedfiles);
        }
        

        public IActionResult Delete(string filedel)
        {
            filedel = Path.Combine("~/Uploads/", filedel);
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filedel);
            if (fi != null)
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(filedel);
                fi.Delete();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

also i get a null reference when trying to delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want `IWebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath`

You need to use Dependency Injection to get access to it, but after that, you can just reference and Path.Combine. See below:

```
public class FileController : Controller
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment environment;

    public FileController(IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        this.environment = env;
    }

    private string UploadFilePath() => Path.Combine(environment.WebRootPath, "uploads");
}
```